# Can waves move the object in the opposite direction of their movement?

Tags: gravity, waves

I'm trying to explain the gravity by the waves, which are emitted by an objects with mass. Can the wave move an other objects to the wave source? Under what conditions?

Comment: you have to clear up whether you are asking about gravity waves  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave or General Relativity gravitational waves https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really the conventional explanation fo gravity these days.

This may interest you.
http://phys.org/news/2015-10-sonic-tractor-video.html